# Are there any unobtrusive ad providers better than Google AdSense?

Tags: ads, adsense

I want to display ads on my site without putting user-experience at risk. Ads must be unobtrusive and blend nicely with the rest of my design.

The best ad implementation I've found is Facebook's skyscraper ads shown on the right side when visiting somebody's profile. Those ads are transparent, not misleading at all, and do not detract visual quality from the rest of the site's design. Is there an ad-serving service that offers a Facebook-like ad layout?

[Google AdSense](http://www.google.com/adsense) is the best provider I've found so far, but it still [looks terrible](https://www.google.com/adsense/static/en/AdFormats.html) to me. What I'm missing in AdSense is the following:

- Ads consisting of a small static image mixed with some text, like Facebook's skyscraper ads. AdSense's text-only ads are very distracting as they add too much textual information to your page (and underlined links *do not* look good...), and the images in the image-only ads are way to big.
- The ability to serve only static image ads, disabling Flash animations and the likes, as animated ads are extremely annoying.

Are there any alternatives to AdSense that offers any of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at: http://www.projectwonderful.com